# Insert fails on first table on iPhone 6 iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I am using 5 SQLite.swift tables in my code. The first table is used to store location data :

DataModel:

```
typealias Location = (
    latitude: Double,
    longitude: Double,
    timestamp: String,
    speed: Double,
    direction: Double
)
```

DataHelper:

```
class LocationDataHelper: DataHelperProtocol {
    static let TABLE_NAME = "Location"

    static let locations = Table(TABLE_NAME)
    static let timestamp = Expression<String>("timestamp")
    static let latitude = Expression<Double>("latitude")
    static let longitude = Expression<Double>("longitude")
    static let speed = Expression<Double>("speed")
    static let direction = Expression<Double>("direction")

    typealias T = Location

    static func createTable() throws {
        guard let DB = SQLiteDataStore.sharedInstance.TeleDB else {
            throw DataAccessError.Datastore_Connection_Error
        }
        do {
            let _ = try DB.run( locations.create(ifNotExists: true) {t in
                t.column(timestamp, primaryKey: true)
                t.column(latitude)
                t.column(longitude)
                t.column(speed)
                t.column(direction)
            })

        } catch _ {
            // Error throw if table already exists
        }

    }

static func insert(item: T) throws -> Int64 {
        guard let DB = SQLiteDataStore.sharedInstance.TeleDB else {
            throw DataAccessError.Datastore_Connection_Error
        }
        if (item.timestamp != "") {
            let insert = locations.insert(timestamp <- item.timestamp, latitude <- item.latitude, longitude <- item.longitude, speed <- item.speed, direction <- item.direction, isDriving <- item.isDriving)
            do {
                let rowId = try DB.run(insert)
                guard rowId > 0 else {
                    throw DataAccessError.Insert_Error
                }
                return rowId
            } catch _ {

                throw DataAccessError.Insert_Error
            }
        }
        throw DataAccessError.Nil_In_Data

    }
```

I see an exception thrown on this line:

```
let rowId = try DB.run(insert)
```

Very similar code run successfully for the other 4 tables in my app on the same phone (iPhone 6, iOS 9.2). The same code also runs without any issues on iPhone 5s, iOS 9.2.

When I tried to step into DB.run I see the failure happening somewhere around this line though I am not sure what it does:

```
dispatch_sync(self.queue, block) // FIXME: rdar://problem/21389236
```

What should I try next? Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Do you need to add isDriving to the data model?